# How to make a gallery lock Application in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to make an application in windows phone which gets the content of gallery and wants to add a security on that files that no body can share that file using blue tooth unless my application allows it..
Application will be made in windows phone 8 ?

Please guide me to the tutorial of how to get the gallery into my application and For the moment lock the application with a password means user with password can access the applicaion ?

Comment: You cannot affect images in Photo gallery in any way possible. You can, however, create your own application for storing images and then password protect them, but they will not be visible in Photos Hub.

Comment: Toni as in android we have facility to import images in app and then apply lock on that and they disappeared from gallery ..Can i do similar in windows phone ... And can you lead me to any tutorial of Making Gallery Lock in windows phone ... Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot do that in Windows Phone. Gallery is read-only. There is no such tutorial on making complete (albeit impossible) applications.

Comment: Did you find any better way??
please suggest me how to create app like photo lock??

Comment: Well in android you can encrypt the files using your app and apply lock on them. For windows I did't got proper solution so I just Implemented the Application in android.

Comment: I believe your looking to create something like [this](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/brilli-gallery-locker/f874229d-d2d7-4feb-842b-1109d15dd44b). Well this is not possible to create in windows phone 8 but in 8.1 WinRT. But there are a lot of restrictions on this. Try playing around with the API's related to files and you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want start develop for Windows Phone i suggest go to:

http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop

But with photolock it's may be problem because apps can't work in that way in Windows Phone. You can lock photogallery by any app. You may only create own app where you can storage photos
into `Isolated Storage` and then restrict access to this by some code etc.

More about Isolated Storage you can find and access to files etc there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Can you lead me any tutorial so that i can write my own application to lock gallery .... And can you give some idead about Isolated Storage or lead me to any tutorial Thanks ...   Can make the app in the same way as in android

Comment: Check: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/save-and-read-data-from-isolated-storage-in-window-phone-7/

And code samples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411